# "null" columns while creating derived column using withColumns

Tags: scala, dataframe

In my dataframe, I have a column named `parent_asset_xid`.

I want to create a new column `parent_asset_sk` which will be `md5(parent_asset_xid)` or `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` if `parent_asset_xid` is `null`.

I am trying something like this but I not sure how to integrate the `md5` part in this

```
mydf.withColumn(
  "parent_asset_sk",
  when($"parent_asset_xid".isnull, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had most of it covered, you just need to add an `otherwise` to you `when`,

```
val newDF = yourDF.withColumn(
  "parent_asset_sk",
  when(
    col("parent_asset_xid").isNotNull, 
    md5(col("parent_asset_xid"))
  ).otherwise(lit("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
)
```